# Get Checkbox states in array - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I just started coding less than 3 weeks ago (took a class in Lynda) and now working on a GUI that enable user to tick/untick a lists. I manage to get it done but in inefficient workaround (someone gave me a heads up on this).

What i have done basically calling a variables for each checkbox and insert the checkbox states into it. So if I have 100 of checkboxes in the list, I will need to create 100 variables. Below is the working code that I wrote.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

var1t1 = tk.IntVar()
var2t1 = tk.IntVar()
var3t1 = tk.IntVar()

var_name = []
root.title("Testing Checkbox")
root.geometry("200x150")

def boxstates_t1():
    var_name = [var1t1.get(), var2t1.get(), var3t1.get()]
    print(var_name)

# -----------------Checkbox-----------------
labelName = tk.Label(root, text = "Name")
labelName.pack(anchor = tk.W)

check1_t1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Mike", variable = var1t1)
check1_t1.pack(anchor = tk.W)

check2_t1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Harry", variable = var2t1)
check2_t1.pack(anchor = tk.W)

check3_t1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Siti", variable = var3t1)
check3_t1.pack(anchor = tk.W)

# -----------------Button-----------------

btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Show", command = boxstates_t1)
btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Then i googled around and found few code that lead me to use for loop to print the list. I initialize the `var_name = []` so that it will capture each checkbox state from the list.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
var1 = tk.IntVar()

var_name = []
root.title("Testing Checkbox")
root.geometry("200x150")

def boxstates():
    var_name = var1.get()
    print(var_name)

# ------------------Chekbox-------------
name1 = ["Mike", "Harry", "Siti"]

labelName = tk.Label(root, text = "Name")
labelName.pack(anchor = tk.W)

for checkboxname in name1:
    check1_t1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text=checkboxname, variable=var1)
    check1_t1.pack(anchor = tk.W)
# ------------------Button-------------
btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Show", command = boxstates)
btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

But I was unable to tick the checkbox independently and the print out result also comes back as if it's in single variable. Am I doing the array `var_name = []` wrongly? I'm currently lost and have no clue where to head next.

Any advise is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def boxstates():
    finalValue = []
    for x in checkboxList:
        finalValue.append(x.get())
    print(finalValue)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Testing Checkbox")
root.geometry("200x150")

# ------------------Chekbox-------------

checkboxList = [tk.IntVar(), tk.IntVar(), tk.IntVar()] # if you want to add more you can either append to it or declare it before runtime
name1 = ["Mike", "Harry", "Siti"]

labelName = tk.Label(root, text = "Name")
labelName.pack(anchor = tk.W)

def createCheckboxes():
    for x, y in zip (checkboxList, name1):
        check1_t1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text=y, variable=x)
        check1_t1.pack(anchor = tk.W)

# ------------------Button-------------
btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Show", command = boxstates)
btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

createCheckboxes()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. But from your revised code, the gui print out all name as "Harry" and add all the boxstate value instead of putting them in array.

Comment: I am sorry. I misread the problem and now I think I fixed it. If you have any problems you can comment again

Comment: It works. Thank you so much @Breno for introducing me to zip function. Just a question in line 25, the 'y' variable was zipped with 'checkboxList' and 'name1'. But it doesn't print out checkboxList, is it because the array do not have any string in it?

Comment: The zip function works like this: You zip as many lists together as you want and for each list you zipped, if you want to access it while zipped you can assign a variable to it. In this case I am doing "for x, y in zip (checkboxList, name1):" and thus the x variable contains all the values of the checkboxList and the y variable contains all the values of the name1 list. They contain the values of the lists they have in order of the zip function - x is the first variable and so contains the values of the first list in the zip which is checkboxList and so on...
You are welcome :D

Comment: I see, I was thinking the x as a counter for the array while y was the variable for both checkboxList and name1. Thanks for your further explanation. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Testing Checkbox")
root.geometry("200x150")

def boxstates():
    for var in vars:
        print (var.get())

names = ["Mike", "Harry", "Siti"]

labelName = tk.Label(root, text = "Name")
labelName.pack(anchor = tk.W)

vars = []

for i, checkboxname in enumerate(names):
    vars.append(tk.IntVar())
    check = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text=checkboxname, variable=vars[i])
    check.pack(anchor = tk.W)

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Show", command = boxstates)
btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. May I ask, in line 19, the checkbox will print out names based on enumerate function, while the i act as a counter for the array?

Comment: Yes, the counter variable "i" covers the range of items in "names" so it takes on the values 0, 1 and 2. I guess the "get" function returns 1 if the corresponding item is checked and 0 otherwise.